# Holomorphic derivatives (in 2 d) in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

In 2 Dimensional Conformal field theory, We have two coordinates $ z=x+i y$ and $\bar{z}=x-i y$. Here $x$ and $y$ are both real. So, one can work directly with $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

I want to define $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$. But there is a little subtlety that $\partial_z \frac{1}{\bar{z}}=2 \pi \delta^2(z,\bar{z})$. One can prove this identity in many ways. The action of the derivative operator on a more general function is like $\partial_z \frac{1}{\bar{z}}f[\bar{z}]=2 \pi f[0]$. Here $f[\bar{z}]$ is well-behaved near 0.

Is there a way to define such an operator in Mathematica? Ordinary derivatives $"D"$ won't really work because of subtlety regarding Delta function.

Comment: It is impossible to implement in Mathematica undefined by you notions $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$.

Comment: The more I consider this, the more I think perhaps you want polar (rather than holomorphic and antiholomorphic) coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say.

The "usual" definitions are like so.

```
z[x_, y_] := x + I*y
zbar[x_, y_] := x - I*y

dbydz[f_, x_, y_] := 1/2*(D[f, x] - I*D[f, y])
```

The minus sign is quite intentional. It compensates for the differential form `dz` behaving as `dx+i*dy`.

First check `dbydz` on `1/z`.

```
dbydz[1/z[x, y], x, y]

(* Out[112]= -(1/(x + I y)^2) *)
```

Now check it on `1/zbar`.

```
dbydz[1/zbar[x, y], x, y]

(* Out[113]= 0 *)
```

Also not a surprise. Just not what you want. From here I do not see the right way to adapt it.

Comment: How about $\partial_z \frac{1}{\bar{z}}f[\bar{z}]=2 \pi f[0]$?

Answer (score -1):

The rule for

```
  D[1/z,w] ~ Delta[z,w]
```

for the Wirtinger partial derivatives in the complex "directions" 1 +- I

is a derivative for a distribution, that in full length reads

```
D[Log[w],w,z] == Laplacian[Log[w]]
```

This has a meaning as an integral kernel in the Cauchy integral sense,  replacing the Cauchy line integral around 0 of 1/z with its value 2 Pi I by an 2d integral with 2-d area form

```
 dw^dz ~ dx dy
```

over the inner of the countour of integration. These identies are  consequences of the universal rule

```
Integral[d f, Volume] = Integral[ f, Boundary[ Volume ]]
```

where df is the volume n-form of a n-1 surface form f. All that can somehow be broken down to 1-d integrals, at least numerically as

```
 Integral[ f', {a,b}] = Integral[ f, b] -Integral[ f, a] =f[b]-f[a]
```

Of course you can knit a Wirtinger calculus for distribution rather straight forward, but better don't use any of the internal D and Derivative algorithms.

Just implement the complete set of caluclus rules from an algorithmic oriented book on functional analysis.

So we conclude, by all the philosophy of working with a CAS-Simplify on localized expressions,  the expression

```
\[Partial]_w (1/z) ==0
```

evaluates locally to zero and the pole at z = 0 is an exception set of measure 0, difficult to hit by chance in a numeric approximation.